# Making inline/horizontal list -- issues with second last child

Tags: css, list, parent-child

[I have seen many questions of a similar kind but those solutions don't work here]

I am making an inline list which should appear like this (depending on number of items):

**First example:** Apples.
**Second example:** Apples and Oranges.
**Third example:** Apples, Oranges and Mangoes.

This CSS is ok:

```
.fruits {font-weight: bold; color: #999999}
.fruits ul {display: inline; padding: 0}
.fruits li {display: inline}
.fruits li:after {content: ", ";}
.fruits li:last-child:after {content: ".";}
```

HTML is this:

```
<div class="fruits">
<ul>
<li>Apples</li>
<li>Oranges</li>
<li>Mangos</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The comma needs to be dropped after nth-2nd child, and be replaced by 'and'.

But I can't make the following work:

```
.fruits li::nth-last-child(2):after {content: "and ";}
```

What am I missing here, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should target your second list item `.fruits` class differently.
The way to do so is like this `.fruits li:nth-child(n)::after { content: " your text" ; }`

The n inside parentheses is the number of the list's item.

```css
.fruits {font-weight: bold; color: #999999}
.fruits ul {display: inline; padding: 0}
.fruits li {display: inline}
.fruits li:after {content: ", ";}
.fruits li:last-child:after {content: ".";}
.fruits li:nth-child(2)::after {content: " and ";}
```

```html
<div class="fruits">
  <ul>
    <li>Apples</li>
    <li>Oranges</li>
    <li>Mangos</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Oris. Now I can stop banging my head against the wall. And thanks for taking time out for this. Much appreciate.

Comment: Done! Yes, I should have done that. Slipped out of my mind totally.